# Distinguish between single line comment and url pattern using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I need help with the pattern to distinguish between single line comments and URLs using a regex, both of them have `//` for example:

```
// this is a single line comment
var foo = "http://google.com";
var bar = 1; // This is another single line comment
```

I want to match comments only and ignore the URLs and other strings that are not comments.

Here is the regex I have tried:

```
/(\/\/.*)/g
```

I am trying to replace the single line comments in the production ready code.

Comment: Hi, try to use :// against //

Comment: @M42 does the php parser works on js?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I don't know if a php parser exists in javascript, but if there isn't, do the job on the server is the best way to go. It's almost impossible to parse php with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?=^\/\/).*
```

Use this.
See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/22

Edit:

Use this is comments can be in middle as well.

```
(?!^http:\/\/.*$)^.*?(\/\/.*$)
```

See demo

http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/29

Comment: what if the comments present at the middle?

Comment: @AvinashRaj that isnt really mentioned in the question neither the regex tried by OP suggests so.

Comment: consider providing a general solution.

Comment: @vks.. partially true. but consider this code statement.. ".success(function (data, status, headers, config) { //Comment goes here"   where comment is present at end of line..  can you correct above answer considering this.

Comment: @vks.. yes tested it too.. but it selected all the preceding char in the statement.. I am using this for removing the comments from production ready code.  it should match all char to the end of line. but not all preceding charecters

Comment: @vks.. I realy appriciate for all your help !!! but lookback not supported in javascript.  can you help me with this in JS?

Comment: @vks .. the matching information is correct. But the substitution part is removing the entire statement. http://regex101.com/r/mK9wZ7/2

Comment: tested for above, version 3 has broken for http:// pattern.... http://regex101.com/r/mK9wZ7/4

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/mK9wZ7/6 not working if http:// is not first char of line:)... guess this will be the last one :)